# Tuning MySQL buffer sizes - Mac Mini 2012 with 16GB

Tags: mysql, buffer, osx-mountain-lion, my.cnf

I'm configuring mySQL buffer sizes.  I find it's really slow.  I'm running mySQL on a i5 mac mini with 16GBRAM OS X Mountain Lion.  My database size is about 10GB.  This is the copy of my.cnf file and I hoped someone could offer some suggestions about getting better performance.

```
[client]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer_size = 2536M
read_buffer_size = 16M 
performance_schema = ON
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1000M
```

Comment: what engine(s) do you use? How much tables per engine do you have? MySQL version? Read/write?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to answer your questions, but I'm not sure if my answer is correct.  The engines I use are InnoDB.  I have about 30 tables in the db.  Some are very large tables (>4GB) and most contain over 4 million rows.  One table contains 200 Million rows.  I use 5.5.29.  Should I change the version considering I am using such large data?  The tables are mostly for reading.  Sometimes I will try to write new tables from the data, but I'm getting timeout errors as well.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G` and you should experience less available ram and faster DB.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you're tuning are mainly MyISAM related. For InnoDB have a look at: [what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/), [innodb-performance-optimization-basics](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/) and [choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/)